# Problema ao instalar o SASS

Tags: css, sass, compass

Baixei o RUBY e instalei me atentando ao “Add Ruby executable to your PATH”

Em seguida instalei o GEM, após isso tento instalar o SASS mas me aparece o seguinte erro conforme na imagem.

A versão do meu Ruby e do GEM estão na imagem, o SASS não instala.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema..

Utilizei no CMD

**gem install -p http://[username]:[password]@proxy_ip:proxy_port [programa]**

E ai funcionou para instalção do SASS e do COMPASS

Answer (score 1):

1 - Vá no https://rubygems.org e baixe a gems sass

2 - Jogue-as na raíz da pasta de instalação do Ruby (normalmente fica no C: )

3 - Ainda na pasta do Ruby, na barra de endereços do explorer, digite cmd . e depois dê Enter, pra abrir o prompt do Windows direto nessa pasta.

4 - Instale o Sass

```
gem install sass
```

Verifique se foram instalados dando

```
 sass -v
```

Answer (score 0):

Use o comando abaixo:

```
gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/
```

aceite usando `y`

depois tente novamente:

```
gem install sass
```

caso ainda não de certo, tente fazer um downgrade da versão do seu ruby.